# writing file with newline in python

Tags: python, file

(I am using thonny don't know if that is part of the error)
I am trying to write to a file but my code,

```
thing = ["hello", "goodbye", "please", "help"]
with open('file123.txt', 'w') as file321:
    file321.writelines(thing)
    file321.close()
```

writes `hellogoodbyepleasehelp` to file123.txt
when I want it to write

```
 hello                                                           
 goodbye                                                                                   
 please                                                                                     
 help
```

I have tried having the list be `thing = ["/nhello", "/ngoodbye", "/nplease", "/nhelp"]`
but that just made the file be */nhello/ngoodbye/nplease/nhelp*

Comment: It's `\n`, not `/n`

Answer (score 1):

To use `writelines` you may have the newline char `\n` appended for each line like

```
thing = ["hello\n", "goodbye\n", "please\n", "help\n"]
with open('file123.txt', 'w') as file321:
    file321.writelines(thing)
```

But the easiest would be to use `str.join`

```
thing = ["hello", "goodbye", "please", "help"]
with open('file123.txt', 'w') as file321:
    file321.write("\n".join(thing))
```